# Increasing Sequence from two arrays

Tags: python

You are given two list of integers a and b of same length n.

find the count of strictly increasing sequences of integers `i[0] < i[1] < ... < i[n-1]` such that

`min(a[i], b[i]) <= i[i] <= max(a[i], b[i])` for each `i`.

example

input:

```
a= [1,3,1,6]
b= [6,5,4,4]
```

Output:

```
4
```

the four sequences  will be :

```
[1,3,4,5]
[1,3,4,6]
[2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5]
```

Here's what I tried

```
a=[1,3,1,6]
b=[6,5,4,4]
P=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i<len(a)-1:
        if max(a[i],b[i])>=max(a[i+1],b[i+1]):
            P.append([x for x in range(min(a[i],b[i]),min(max(a[i],b[i]),max(a[i+1],b[i+1])))])
        else:
            P.append([x for x in range(min(a[i],b[i]),1+min(max(a[i],b[i]),max(a[i+1],b[i+1])))])
    else:
        P.append([x for x in range(min(a[i],b[i]),max(a[i],b[i])+1)])
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i<len(a)-1 and P[i+1][-1]<=P[i][-1]:
        P[i]=[x for x in range(P[i][0],P[i+1][-1])]
    if i>0 and P[i][0]<=P[i-1][0]:
        P[i]=[x for x in range(P[i-1][0]+1,1+P[i][-1])

cnt=1
for i in P:
    cnt*=len(i)
print(cnt)
```

What I did is that I took this setup

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
    3 4 5 
1 2 3 4
      4 5 6
```

and reduced it to this

```
1 2
   3 
    4 
      5 6
```

removing all numbers that wouldn't make it to the sequence.

Now what I do is, Just multiply the len of each row-wise sequence.
The problem arises when there is a case such as this.

```
1 2 3
    3 4
      4 5
        5 6
```

Now the simple multiplication of the lengths doesn't hold up.
This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Please show some effort from yourself first. This kind of questions (no effort -> I want solution) is discouraged on stackoverflow

Comment: I've added my approach

Comment: Much much better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of problem that lends itself to a recursive solution, so here is a possible alternative implementation. (Sorry I haven't tried to get to grips with your code, maybe someone else will.)

```
def sequences(a, b, start_index=0, min_val=None):
    """
    yields a sequence of lists of partial solutions to the original
    problem for sublists going from start_index to the end of the list
    subject to the constraint that the first value cannot be less than
    min_val (if not None)
    Example: with a=[3,4,5,6], b=[6,5,0,4], start_index=2, minval=4, 
    it is looking at the [5,6] and the [0,4] part, and it would yield
     [4,5] [4,6] and [5,6]
    If the start index is not already the last one, then it uses a
    recursive call.
    """
    limits = a[start_index], b[start_index]
    lower = min(limits)
    higher = max(limits)
    if min_val is not None and min_val > lower:
        lower = min_val  # impose constraint
    options = range(lower, higher + 1)
    is_last = start_index == len(a) - 1
    for val in options:
        if is_last:
            yield [val]
        else:
            # val followed by each of the lists from the recursive 
            # callback - passing min_val=val+1 imposes the constraint
            # of strictly increasing numbers
            for seq in sequences(a, b, start_index+1, min_val=val+1):
                yield [val, *seq]

for seq in sequences([1,3,1,6], [6,5,4,4]):
    print(seq)
```

This gives:

```
[1, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Note that I don't claim that the above is particularly *efficient*: the recursive function may get called more than once with the same arguments -- e.g. whether you start with 1,3 or 2,3 it will be doing the same calculations to work out what can come next -- so you might want to implement some kind of caching before using it with large lists.  Obviously though, caching has a memory overhead, so working out the best overall strategy to cope with this could be a rather harder problem.

Comment: could you explain your approach.

Comment: I'll add a doc string to the function which should hopefully help.

Comment: that'll be great